# Bash for loop get previous and next item

Tags: bash, loops

I would like to do a loop and inside the loop get the previous and the next item.

Currently, I am using the following loop:

```
for file in $dir;do
    [...do some things...]
done
```

Can I do things like in C, for example, file[i-1]/file[i+1] to get the previous and the next item? Is there any simple method to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
declare -a files=(*)
for (( i = 0; i < ${#files[*]}; ++ i ))
do
  echo ${files[$i-1]} ${files[$i]} ${files[$i+1]}
done
```

In the first iteration, the index -1 will print the last element and in the last iteration, the index max+1 will not print anything.

Comment: My bash doesn't wrap the first -1 or last +1 though.

Comment: last+1 will not be wrapped. first-1 should be, may be your bash version is old, it works in bash version 4.

Comment: I misread the +1 case. My bash is 4.1.2(1) as supplied with CentOS 6.3. Running your script in a directory with files a,b,c produces the following output: 
a b\n
a b c\n
b c\n

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
previous=
current=
for file in *; do
  previous=$current
  current=$next
  next=$file
  echo $previous \| $current \| $next 
  #process item
done
previous=$current
current=$next
next=
echo $previous \| $current \| $next 
#process last item
```

Comment: Use `*` in place of `\`ls\``.